# Cannot convert type of expression data from java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> to java.util.ArrayList<com.demo.Profile>

Tags: android

I create Profile class, like

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String Name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    private String type;

   GET SET value set hear.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n{" +
                "pid=" + pid +
                ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                ", Location='" + location + '\'' +
                ", Type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}' + "\n";
    }
}
```

then in my Activity class, I want to shared this data into another Activity parse through Intent. How it is possible?

IN Activity class

```
    private List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Profile profile = new Profile();
                    profile.setPid(new Random().nextInt());
                    profile.setName(mName);
                    profile.setLocation(mLocation);
                    profile.setType(mType);

                   data.all(profileList);
```

My DAO class

```
@Dao
public interface ProfileDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM profile")
    List<Profile> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE pid IN (:userIds)")
    List<Profile> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Profile... profiles);

    @Delete
    void delete(Profile profile);

    @Update
    void update(Profile... profiles);
}
```

And the same data of profileList saved in String then I 'll send in one Activity to another Activity.
Thank in advance ..!

Comment: Can you paste your DAO interface please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra`

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data", mArraylist);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

**OR**

Try using gson as below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    String jsonprofileList  = gson.toJson(profileList );

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("profile_list ", jsonprofileList  );
    startActivity(intent);
```

and receive it like

```
String profileListAsString = getIntent().getStringExtra("profile_list");

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<modelClass>>(){}.getType();
List<modelClass> profileList = gson.fromJson(profileListAsString , type);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(AddDataActivity.this,ShowListData.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("profileData",profileList);

Comment: Try using gson as explained above, For include gson use implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'